# Parsing json with an odd format

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

Note:  Please post in comments if you have a better title for this post.  Thanks!

I am working with an api that returns json that looks like the snippet below.  I am pretty familiar with json but I have never seen a structure that looks like this.

The resultFieldList fieldNames are fixed (4 below but there are about 20).  The values array is variable, but the same length for each fieldName.

I am thinking that I should count a non-null field (OrderNumber) and then iterate through each fieldName, but that seems inefficient.  I am wondering if there is a better way.  This is how I am getting the record count:

```
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject m_json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
int m_count = m_json["resultFieldList"][3]["values"].Count();
```

This is the json snippet.

```
{
"collectionName": "Transactions",
"recordCount": 0,
"skippedRecordCount": 0,
"resultFieldList": 
  [{
    "fieldName": "SaleChannel",
    "analyticsDataType": "STRING",
    "values": ["Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online"]
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "Quantity",
    "analyticsDataType": "INTEGER",
    "values": [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "Amount",
    "analyticsDataType": "CURRENCY",
    "values": ["25.00", "14.00", "14.00", "50.00", "14.00", "50.00", "14.00", "25.00", "18.00", "50.00", "36.00", "25.00", "50.00", "25.00", "14.00", "25.00", "50.00", "50.00", "25.00", "75.00"]
  }, 
  {
    "fieldName": "OrderNumber",
    "analyticsDataType": "STRING",
    "values": ["60937129", "60937129", "53221966", "14599547", "14599547", "10478305", "10478305", "95344699", "95344699", "83413371", "65720270", "43458148", "52500933", "32742144", "32742144", "89850688", "61514108", "11080559", "90497730", "22838522"]
  }]
}
```

The precise question is is it possible to create a new array or object where the index of each value is combined into a new object given this structure.  For example, the values of index[0] are "Online",1,"25.00","60937129".  So it may be a new array or a whole new json object.  If so, how would I create either one or the other?  The output would be something like this:

```
[ { "Online",1,"25.00","60937129" },{...} ]
```

Or

```
{"results": [ { "SaleChannel": "Online" , "Quantity": 1, "Amount": "25.00", "OrderNumber": "60937129" } , {...} ]
```

ANSWER

Using @JLRishe's answer I am able to parse and use the data for the use case - inserting api data into a data warehouse.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you're describing here: _"I am thinking that I should count a non-null field (OrderNumber) and then iterate through each fieldName"_ Could you explain more clearly? What is the trouble you're having and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you're trying to do? You don't state what the goal of your "parsing" actually is?

Comment: and regarding the line quoted by @JLRishe, can you provide a code sample of what you meant?

Comment: A "typical" json structure would be an array of orders and each order has attributes such as OrderNumber, Quantity, Amount, and SaleChannel.  This json is obviously not like that, The question is what is the best way to parse the json without doing 20 iterations.

Comment: @smoore4 So is this question about parsing, or about rearranging the data into something closer to your conception of what an order's data structure would look like?

Comment: I've tried to clarify by providing expected output, but the original question is more about an efficient approach, including the possibility that I just need to iterate through the fields.

Comment: @smoore4 Are the resultFields always in the same order and with the same fields (SaleChannel first, then Quantity, etc.)?

Comment: yes, they are always in the same order.

Comment: @smoore4 Ok, I think the end of my answer (just edited) pretty much addresses what you're getting at.

Comment: Have you ever had to convert a collection of objects into rows in a CSV? Or at least thought about doing it? This is essentially an object that is the same structure as a CSV. So you just need to do the reverse. First things first, deserialize into the literal structure. Then convert each column (each iteration across all fields) into an instance of a "normal" POJO object with a property for each field.

Comment: JLRishe and Novaterata are absolutely right.  I was over-thinking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I believe I have addressed the main point of your question toward the end of my answer.

You're probably best off defining a type to represent this structure. Since the contents of the `values` arrays have varying types, you can't really make an assumption about them and would probably be safest treating them as `object`s:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string collectionName { get; set; }

    public int recordCount { get; set; }

    public int skippedRecordCount { get; set; }

    public ResultField[] resultFieldList { get; set; }
}

public class ResultField
{
    public string fieldName { get; set; }

    public string analyticsDataType { get; set; }

    public object[] values { get; set; }
}
```

Then parsing the JSON is simply a matter of:

```
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(result);
```

When actually using the data, you would need to look at the value in `analyticsDataType` for each respective `ResultField` and cast the contents of the `values` properties accordingly.

Alternatively, if you don't care that much about treating the `values` as their original types, you could treat them all as strings, which would require less type checking. Everything else would remain the same:

```
public string[] values { get; set; }
```

---

**Edit:** Now that you've clarified the question a bit more, it seems this is mostly about arranging the data into a more nicely consumable fashion.

If there isn't anything outside the `resultFieldList` that indicates the number of values in each `value` array, then you would basically need to arbitrarily pick one to get the count:

```
int valueCount = obj.resultFieldList[0].values.Length;
```

Then once you have that, you could assemble the values together:

```
// assuming OrderItem is a class you've defined with the needed 
// properties for one entry in an order
IEnumerable<OrderItem> items = Enumerable
    .Range(0, valueCount)
    .Select(i => new OrderItem {
         SaleChannel = Convert.ToString(obj.resultFieldList[0].values[i]),
         Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(obj.resultFieldList[1].values[i]),
         Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(obj.resultFieldList[2].values[i]),
         // etc...
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that is exactly it.  You and @Novaterata both opened my eyes to the answer.  Mainly that I needed to think about this more like a .csv and not worry about merging arrays or rewriting the json.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.Json and do something like this:

1. Define your classes:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public List<DynamicProperty> resultFieldList { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicProperty
{
    public string fieldName { get; set; }

    public string analyticsDataType { get; set; }

    public List<object> values { get; set; }
}
```

2. Deserialize your JSON:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(json);
var t = obj.resultFieldList[3].values.Count();
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.  I tested using your JSON and the answer was 20.  Additionally, you could use Linq to do more complex analysis.

Edited: Based on question being expanded.

3. Create an Order class:

```
public class Order
{
    public string SaleChannel { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

4. Generate the json enumerable based and serialize:

```
var jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Enumerable
    .Range(0, obj.resultFieldList.Max(x => x.values.Count))
    .Select(i => new Order()
    {
        SaleChannel = obj.resultFieldList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fieldName == nameof(Order.SaleChannel))?.values[i].ToString(),
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(obj.resultFieldList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fieldName == nameof(Order.Quantity))?.values[i].ToString()),
        Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(obj.resultFieldList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fieldName == nameof(Order.Amount))?.values[i].ToString()),
        OrderNumber = obj.resultFieldList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fieldName == nameof(Order.OrderNumber))?.values[i].ToString()
    }));
```